# python plt.plot with incomplete indeces

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, append

```
p = [] 
for i in range(len(f)):
    p.append(peakdetect(H, 0.1)) 
plt.plot(Freq[p], f)
```

Because the whole code is complex so I only attach the part where the bug is.

I want to plot a graph about Freq and f. And p is the index shows below,

```
[[126, 269, 409, 542],
 [145, 288, 427, 558],
 [162, 305, 443, 572],
 [177, 320, 457],
 [191, 334, 471],
 [204, 347, 483],
 [217, 359, 494],
 [228, 370, 504],
 [238, 380, 513],
 [248, 389, 521],
 [257, 398, 528],
 [265, 406, 535],
 [273, 414, 541],
 [280, 421, 546],
 [287, 428, 551],
 [294, 434],
 [300, 440],
 [306, 445],
 [312, 451],
 [317, 455],
 [322, 460],
 [327, 464],
 [331, 468],
 [336, 472],
 [340, 476],
 [344, 479],
 [348, 482],
 [351, 486],
 [355, 488],
 [358, 491],
 [361, 494],
 [364, 496],
 [367, 498],
 [370, 500],
 [373, 502],
 [375, 504],
 [378, 506],
 [380, 507],
 [383, 509],
 [385, 510],
 [387, 511],
 [389, 512],
 [392, 513],
 [394, 514],
 [395, 515],
 [397, 515],
 [399, 516],
 [401, 516],
 [403],
 [404],
 [406],
 [408],
 [409],
 [411],
 [412],
 [413],
 [415],
 [416],
 [417],
 [419],
 [420]]
```

in which,

```
f[0] corresponds to [126, 269, 409, 542]
f[1] corresponds to [145, 288, 427, 558]
f[2] corresponds to [162, 305, 443, 572]
f[3] corresponds to [177, 320, 457]
f[4] corresponds to [191, 334, 471]

...
```

You see, the list p doesn't complete 4 columns, so when I run it, it shows the error: **only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.**

So one way I think is to complete the rest of the column with None, but I'm not sure. Another way is to slice the column but with list character, it's difficult to manipulate.

peakdetect(H, 0.1) is a self-defined function. No worries for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` your problem is super easy to solve:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[126, 269, 409, 542],
 [145, 288, 427, 558],
 [162, 305, 443, 572],
 [177, 320, 457],
 [191, 334, 471],
 [204, 347, 483],
 [217, 359, 494],
 [228, 370, 504],
 [238, 380, 513],
 [248, 389, 521],
 [257, 398, 528],
 [265, 406, 535],
 [273, 414, 541],
 [280, 421, 546],
 [287, 428, 551],
 [294, 434],
 [300, 440],
 [306, 445],
 [312, 451],
 [317, 455],
 [322, 460],
 [327, 464],
 [331, 468],
 [336, 472],
 [340, 476],
 [344, 479],
 [348, 482],
 [351, 486],
 [355, 488],
 [358, 491],
 [361, 494],
 [364, 496],
 [367, 498],
 [370, 500],
 [373, 502],
 [375, 504],
 [378, 506],
 [380, 507],
 [383, 509],
 [385, 510],
 [387, 511],
 [389, 512],
 [392, 513],
 [394, 514],
 [395, 515],
 [397, 515],
 [399, 516],
 [401, 516],
 [403],
 [404],
 [406],
 [408],
 [409],
 [411],
 [412],
 [413],
 [415],
 [416],
 [417],
 [419],
 [420]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. 

But the problem is p is the index, so it has the error: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Does df work well for this kind of problem?